# Typing g++ --version is showing the wrong version in windows

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, mingw

I am on Windows 7, installed MinGW a while ago, now I need to use it but I need g++ version 5.4.0 and above. So I went into MinGW Installation Manager and updated `mingw32-gcc-g++` to the latest (repository) version 9.2.1 as is shown in the picture here:
[image]

But then when I go to check on the command prompt it shows that it hasn't updated at all:

```
    C:\>g++ --version
    g++ (GCC) 5.2.0
    Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
    This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
    warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

It still shows me that I am on version 5.2.0. I tried restarting the PC which didn't work. I decided to uninstall everything and reinstall, so I checked in "Control Panel>Programs And Features" but I didn't find anything with g++, gcc or TMD-GCC as some people online were saying.

So my question is how do I update gcc and make it show up on the command prompt as the correct version?

Comment: Do you perhaps have another `g++` in your path? Probably one that has come with `MSys`? You might want to check `echo %path%` in `cmd.exe` or `echo $PATH$` in `MSys`.

Comment: It always feels strange to me watching others suffer through attempting  to shoehorn gcc into windows, when it takes almost no time at all to install Linux from scratch and get a fully configured, current version of gcc, out of the box.

Comment: In a command prompt run `where g++.*`

Comment: @BenjaminBihler I checked `echo %path%` as you suggested, it returns a bunch of paths, I put them in a notepad and organised them: The only path of interest was `C:\MinGW\bin`. The others were Intel, Windows/system32, etc.. If there is nothing that contains `Msys`. (Excuse my ignorance about Msys I did a quick search but could not really understand how it fits here). I did not use or come across it in all of this (to the best of my knowledge)

Comment: @RichardCritten I did, the result was: `C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe`

Comment: Hmmm, your mingw32-base version seems to be from 2013. So this is probably version 5.2.0. Your mingw32-gcc-g++ on the other hand seems to be a current version. Is such a mixture okay? How did it happen?

Comment: @BenjaminBihler I think it happened because I installed MinGW a while ago and now I came back to update it, maybe something went wrong there (?). When I search "9.2.0" or 5.2.0 in `C:\MinGW` I get results in both cases, almost as if they are both installed at the same time. Here are both my search results if that helps: https://imgur.com/a/Zruvmz6

Comment: Then you could clean up your installation (remove and reinstall?) or use the executables that have a version number in it, if you insist on having installed both versions at once.

Comment: @BenjaminBihler I deleted the whole MinGW folder and reinstalled everything from scratch. It is working now. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Okay, I will post my comments as an answer...

Comment: I would recommend uninstalling all this junk and installing mingw-w64 which is much more up to date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshot of the installation manager shows that you have installed different versions of MinGW. Your mingw32-base version seems to be from 2013. So this is probably version 5.2.0. Your mingw32-gcc-g++ on the other hand seems to be a current version.

Cleaning up your installation (removing and reinstalling from scratch) solves the version problem.